# Match-Anything Pattern Rules

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I am using GNU Make 3.81 version.

From the following example, I expect match anything pattern(%:) has to be print. Instead of that **te%:** has executed.

Can some one explain, why target '**%:**' did not run?

Is this not match all file name?

Makefile:

```
all: test
    echo $@
%: 
    echo 1: $@
te%:
    echo 2: $@
```

Output:

```
echo 2: test
2: test
echo all
all
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are special rules for how make treats match-anything pattern rules; see the [documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Match_002dAnything-Rules.html).  You are creating a "non-terminal match-anything rule" here, and the rule for that is this:

> A non-terminal match-anything rule cannot apply to a file name that indicates a specific type of data. A file name indicates a specific type of data if some non-match-anything implicit rule target matches it.

In your case you have a non-match-anything implicit rule target (`te%`) which matches the file name (`test`) and so a non-terminal match-anything rule (`%:`) cannot match it.